# Unable to load image of particular website using react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

unable to load images please help

I am helpless to load images

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const logoUri = 'https://www.dcpexpeditions.com/journal/3.jpg';
...
          <Image
            accessibilityLabel="React logo"
            source={{ uri: logoUri }}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={styles.logo}
          />
...
```

Comment: did you set the height and width in the style `logo`?

Answer (score 0):

your issue relates with Style `logo` you should add width and height to your image,

so try this

```
logo:{
   width: '100%',
   height: '100%'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DevAS but I already have a css in place  ```logo: {
    height: 80,
    width: 50
  }, ```
I am able to load 
const logoUri = 'https://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg'; 
but not able to load const logoUri = 'https://www.dcpexpeditions.com/journal/3.jpg';

Comment: I've already loaded "https://www.dcpexpeditions.com/journal/3.jpg" in my app and yeah it's loaded! what's wrong with you? open the debugger and check it and tell me what you see "errors or warnnig"

Comment: are you using react-native? I get a blank screen no errors and warning? Can you share code ?

Comment: I'm using the same code you are writing, and just apply the CSS style! `<Image source={{uri:imgLink}} style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}} resizeMode='contains />`

Comment: *imgLink* url please is it https://www.dcpexpeditions.com/journal/3.jpg?